# UIbutton does not reset to default after click on Reset button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, reload

I have a product filter list and I would like to reset all data to default (without click) after clicked on Reset button.

[image]

But now my case is after I clicked on Reset button, selected items will not reset accordingly and it will change to other items. You may refer to screenshot as below:-

[image]

Here is my part of related code, please help and thanks for your advice:-

**FilterItemCell.m**

```
- (void)setUpUI
{

    _contentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_contentButton setTitleColor: ThemeBlueColor
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_contentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_contentButton];

}

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
          !_attributeItemClick ? : _attributeItemClick();
        [sender setSelected: NO];
        [_contentButton setImage:nil forState:0];
        [_contentButton setTitleColor:ThemeBlueColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {
          !_attributeItemClick ? : _attributeItemClick();
        [sender setSelected: YES];
        [_contentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"isSelectYes"] forState:0];
        [_contentButton setTitleColor:ThemeRedColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

**Filter_ViewController.m**

```
- (void)setUpBottomButton
{
    CGFloat buttonW = FiltrateViewScreenW/2;
    CGFloat buttonH = 40;
    CGFloat buttonY = ScreenH -10 - buttonH;
    NSArray *titles = @[@"Reset",@"OK"];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < titles.count; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = i;

        CGFloat buttonX = i*buttonW;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);
        button.titleLabel.font = PFR16Font;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button2-1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(bottomButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        else if (i == 1)
        {
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button1-1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(bottomButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {

        }

        [_filtrateConView addSubview:button];
    }
}

- (void)bottomButtonClick:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (button.tag == 0) //Reset Button
    {
         //CURRENT CODE TO RELOAD COLLECTION VIEW DATA
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FilterItemCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:FilterItemCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.attribute_name=[[self.filterItem[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Whats the code for reset button?

Comment: is bottomButtonClick method for rest code?

Comment: Add the collectionview cell for item code.

Comment: @JasveerSingh， added and updated as above.

Comment: You need to keep all the selected items in an array and in cellForRowAtIndex just check if the current item is in the selected array then set the item as selected else set the item as not selected.

When you want to reset the list, remove all items from the selected array and reload collection view. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for reset function you need to renew all the data as in starting like you might be storing the ticked ones in an array.

you need to refresh the array you are using to display in your collectionView.
Then you need to call reload on your collectionView.

In your function I can see only reload function call not any function for refreshing the data in the array you might be using to display in the collection view.

I hope this helps you. Do let me know in case you need anything else.